# Latex Subscripting

Tags: support, mathjax, formatting

How do I write $\ce{C_{2}{v}}$ properly in Latex so that the "2" and the "v" are both subscripted on the same subscript line? If I write it as $\ce{C_{2v}}$ (\ce{C_{2v}), I get an down-arrow symbol replacing the "v".

Comment: Try using just `$ $` instead of `\ce{}`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!

Comment: The axis should be written in italic. Do not use the mhchem environment when not writing formulas - it is still actively developed and the might introduce new features, that ruin your intended layout. If you want non italics, use `\mathrm` instead. In you case, it should be written as `$C_{\mathrm{2v}}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put an extra brace around the `v`: `\ce{C_{2{v}}}`

$$\ce{C_{2{v}}}$$